# Combined scatterplot with edited lab and ylab in ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a PCA and would also like to include the percent of variation on the axis. This works fine when I do the plots one by one. But I would like to include both plots into one figure containing both plots next to each other and one legend.

library("ggpubr")

```
[b <- ggplot(table, aes(column_1, column2, col=ethnicity_type)) + geom_point()
#b <- b + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
b <- b + coord_equal() + theme_light()
b + xlab(paste0("PC1 (", signif(pve$pve\[1\], 3), "%)")) + ylab(paste0("PC2 (", signif(pve$pve\[2\], 3), "%)"))


# Create a violin plot
c <- ggplot(table, aes(column_1, column_2, col=ethnicity_type)) + geom_point()
#b <- b + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
c <- c + coord_equal() + theme_light()
c + xlab(paste0("PC1 (", signif(pve$pve\[1\], 3), "%)")) + ylab(paste0("PC3 (", signif(pve$pve\[3\], 3), "%)"))

figure <- ggarrange(b, c,
                    labels = c("A", "B"),
                    ncol = 2, nrow = 1,
                    common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")][1]
```

[image: This is how one picture looks like with the labelled axis]

Comment: Very general (and maybe unsolicited) advice; don't use `c` as a variable name. It gets easily confused with the `c()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there if I understand what you want.  I did it like this:

```
set.seed(45301)
z1 <- rnorm(100)
z2 <- rnorm(100)
dat <- data.frame(
  x1 = z1 + .5*rnorm(100),
  x2 = z2 + .5*rnorm(100),
  x3 = z1 + z2 + rnorm(100),
  x4 = -z1 + .5*z1 + .6*rnorm(100),
  x5 = .5*z1 + z2 + .7*rnorm(100),
  ethnicity_type = factor(sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE), 
                 labels = paste0("Group", 1:3))
)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)
p <- princomp(scale(dat %>% select(contains("x"))))
pve <- list(pve =  p$sdev^2/sum(p$sdev^2))
dat$column_1 <- p$scores[,1]
dat$column_2 <- p$scores[,2]
dat$column_3 <- p$scores[,3]

library(ggplot2)
b <- ggplot(dat, aes(column_1, column_2, col=ethnicity_type)) + geom_point()
#b <- b + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
b <- b + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(-4,4)) + theme_light() 
b <- b + xlab(paste0("PC1 (", signif(pve$pve[1], 3), "%)")) + ylab(paste0("PC2 (", signif(pve$pve[2], 3), "%)"))


# Create a violin plot
c <- ggplot(dat, aes(column_1, column_3, col=ethnicity_type)) + geom_point()
#b <- b + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
c <- c + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(-4,4)) + theme_light() 
c <- c + xlab(paste0("PC1 (", signif(pve$pve[1], 3), "%)")) + ylab(paste0("PC3 (", signif(pve$pve[3], 3), "%)"))

figure <- ggarrange(b, c,
                    labels = c("A", "B"),
                    ncol = 2, nrow = 1,
                    common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")
```

[image]